# JSF web app not working on deployment but works locally

Tags: java, jsf, deployment, glassfish

Dears,

Environemt details:

*JSF Web app using hibernate, jsf tags, and primefaces.

*Eclipse

*Glassfish

*Team Server: Mercurial

Problem: 
I deployed one version and it got deployed successfully, I made few more changes to the last version which I deployed, made sure it works with no errors on my local machine then deployed it, but when I deployed it said it got deployed successfully, and when accessing the website it gives 500 HTTP ERROR, even though I added

```
<error-page>
        <location>/errorHandlers/ErrorRedirect.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
```

It still doesn't go to the error page so I can at least know why is this happening. 
The confusing thing is that it works perfectly fine on my local machine.

Comment: Update your post with the content of the Glassfish log around the time you got the HTTP 500 error. There is probably a stack trace.

Comment: @skomisa glassfish server log is not updated at all..

Comment: OK. HTTP 500 means that there was an error on the server, so it's strange that Glassfish is not reporting its own error. I doubt if it will help, but is it possible to restart the Glassfish server and try again? Also: [1] Are you using the same version of Glassfish in both environments? [2] What version(s) of Glassfish are you using?

Comment: @skomisa I'm using version 3. The new thing I added to the code is that I added (Send emails notification to users), I'm suspecting that connecting to the email server or whatever related is causing this issue. Can this be a reason? even though as I mentioned before, it works perfectly fine on my local machine.

Comment: OK. Does your non-local web application always fail with HTTP 500, or only when it sends email notifications? Also, is it possible to check the logs on the email server regarding the HTTP 500 error?

Comment: I was working OK before adding send email feature. I did 1)edit the code and added emails notifications feature. 2) tested it locally and it was working 100%. 3) deployed it on the server. 4) got deployment success in console output. 5) went to the same website URL and it gives 500 HTTP ERROR. I can't even see the homepage.@skomisa

Comment: OK. [1] Are you using the same email server for both the local deployment of your app that works, and the non-local deployment of your app that fails? [2] Is any other server used in your non-local configuration between the browser and the Glassfish server? For example: IIS, or an Apache web server? [3] Is everything you are doing using only HTTP, or are you using HTTPS?

Comment: I just realized what the issue was. There are two classes have the same name and same package name. one of them is inside the project while the other one is another one, and my app was using the one outside instead

Comment: It's good that you resolved it. Could you post that as the answer for your own question? That will be helpful for the community since most people won't read through a lot of comments, and I don't think that has been given as the solution for any problem on Stack Overflow.